# SignalR issue where presumably several hubs are being created and messages are getting lost

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, signalr, unity-container

I'm using unity as IoC container, and I'm using SignalR. This is how I configure SignalR, in Startup.cs, inside the Configure method

```
 app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                Log.Information($"Initializing app on ->{DateTime.Now}");
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
                hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                hubConfiguration.EnableJavaScriptProxies = false;
                // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
                // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
                // path.
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
```

As you can see, I have a log inside the .Map method. Most of the times, when I deploy, I can se 2 or 3 of those logs.
Below is the code in the controller endpoint that sends the message using SignalR hub.

```
// do something else inside the endpoint
// ...................
//grab hub context and send message
 IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
 await context.Clients.All.sendNotify(send);
//.....
// some other controller code
```

That endpoint can be consumed mainly by two sources:

1. Azure LogicApp
2. Postman

When consumed by Postman everything works fine, frontend receives 100% notifications. When consumed by the LogicApp, most messages never arrive to frontend.
There are times where only one log appears in the initialization code after a new deploy or restart, on those occasions messages sent by both Postman and LogicApp are received in frontend 100%.

My question is: Could it be that my issue is that the Configure method inside the Startup class is running more than once and creating multiple hubs?